# Options to return a custom complex object from a spring data jpa

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get the data from MSSQL database using below logic. Couldnt identify the option to prepare a single query (SQL or JPQL) to get the repository reponse as MyTestSTO.Can someone suggest me the options available to acheive this.

Expected object Format :

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Test",
        "CabInfo": {
          "CabStatus": 0,
          "CabStatusStr": "Active",
          "CabFunctionalArea": {
            "FunctionalAreaId": 3
            },
          "CabApplication": {
            "ApplicationId": 333,
            "ApplicationAcronym": "OBM Router"
          }
        }
      }
       



And JPARepository Class  is :




public interface FloorPlanRepositoryExt extends JpaRepository<Sites, Long> { 
  
  //Other APIs on Sites Table.
  Can we use multiple news in below query ?
  @Query(value = "select new TestDTo(sp.id,sp.name,sp.cabStatus,sp.cabStatusStr, 
  sp.functionalArea,sp.applicationId,sp.ApplicationAcronym) from SpacePower sp where sp.roomId=:roomId)
  public List<TestDTo> getRoomSpacesCabByRoomId(@Param("roomId")Integer roomId);
  }
```

My custom DTO is below:

```
class TestDTo implements serializable{
  
  private String id;
  privateString name;
  private CabInfo cabInfo
  //Setters and getters and Constructor
  }





 class CabInfo{
  
  private String cabStatus;
  private String CabStatusStr;
  
  private CabFunctionalArea cabFunctionalArea;
  private CabApplication CabApplication;
  //Setters and getters and Constructor
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In select query you expect `TestDTo` but in return method you define `RoomSpacesCabDTO`

Comment: Sorry, i missed correcting to TestDTO. Any idea how do we add CabInfo object in Repository